# q-analogies of Exponential and Logarithmic functions

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, inverse-function

From several different sources, I found two different [q-analogies](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWuqKjkrvRAhWLqlQKHQAqAscQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FQ-analog&usg=AFQjCNFWPwJ91qHU7gqAFyh7BoFjNIMoYw) of the Exponential function.
  According to [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ4--TjrvRAhXrz1QKHY7fBLcQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fplouffe.fr%2Fsimon%2Fmath%2FQuantum%2520calculus%2520-%2520Kac%2520V.%2520%26%2520Cheung%2520P..pdf&usg=AFQjCNGDzFteGczDg15AQQlnZ1Ri3aqsWA) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-exponential) sources exponential function has two q-analogies given by: $$\exp_q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{[n]_q!}.\tag1$$ 
and
 $$\text{Exp}_q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\dfrac{x^n}{[n]_q!}.\tag2$$

However, the q-derivative of the second is not exactly itself.
So the most natural definition is the first one (for me ) and I would like to know that:

> Is there an inverse (logarithmic) function for the q-exponential function defined in $(1)$ ?

Comment: [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilpO7mqbvRAhWIhlQKHQljCIwQFggdMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F0709.1788&usg=AFQjCNHlJdfHJLIljI-QF3ZVoUUTB_Vugw) I found few different definitions of  q-logarithms. But no one mention as the inverse of   $\exp_q(x).$

Comment: You can try the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)